# MaterialButton wider than it should be warning

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, material-ui, materialbutton

I use in my Android app, xml files to render the UI.

In my xml files I use Google's `MaterialButton` from `com.google.android.material.button` to render a button at the bottom of a screen.

More specifically I define it in a `ConstraintLayout` like this:

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/continue_button"
    style="@style/MyTheme.MaterialComponents.Button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="@string/continue"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

I notice that Android Studio (I'm using Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1) reports this `Layout Validation` warning:

> The button continue_button  is too wide
>
> The button MaterialButton is wider than 320dp in 4 preview configurations. Material Design recommends buttons to be no wider than 320d

**Questions:**

- What does this warning actually mean? I'm not sure where I can find these "preview configurations" it's mentioning.
- How can I resolve this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By defining the layout_width="0dp" & end & start to parent.

That means the button is as wide as the ConstraintLayout. (- 64dp padding + margin)
This is a lint check that looks at how the layout will look in various screen sizes.
Checking for things like overlapping widgets etc.

If your design intent is to have a 320dp wide button on a 384dp or greater then ignore. (there is probably a tool attribute) But it is typically a strange UI look to have a very wide button in Android.

You can also set the maximum width you want by setting the `app:layout_constraintWidth_max="..."` attribute.

Comment: android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
does not work for me. I still have the warning